# Android ListView child View setEnabled() and setClickable() do nothing

Tags: android, listview

I'm doing some `AsyncTask` work after user clicks an item in my `ListView`. I'd like to disable the item so it can't be clicked twice. I've simplified the click listener to contain only this method, but it still doesn't do anything for me, the view looks the same and it lets itself be happily clicked again, much to my annoyance.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View clickedView,
  int position, long id) {
  item = (Episode) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
  clickedView.setClickable(false);
  clickedView.setEnabled(false);
  clickedView.invalidate();
}
```

My View for each row is a custom `LinearLayout` with two `TextView`s.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So, you may be using a custom adapter too. If you do, override these methods:

```
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // return false if position == position you want to disable
}
```

Then, when you receive a click tell the adapter what was the last item clicked and return false on `isEnabled` for that position. For instance, you can have a method like this in your adapter:

```
private int mLastClicked;
public void setLastClicked(int lastClicked){
    mLastClicked = lastClicked;
}
```

Comment: hi im having a hard time getting the position of the last item clicked can you enlighten me up for this thanks

Answer (score 19):

If you want disabling item click in list view use `clickedView.setClickable(true);`

Comment: This sounds very wrong, but for whatever reason, it works. Strange, maybe a pro can enlighten us why setClickable(true) will actually have the desired effect of making the view non-clickable.

Comment: indead! Looks like a bug in the system.

Comment: I think this is not a bug. This way `clickedView` intercepts the click. The list element will not respond to any click because `clickedView` intercepts them, hence the list element won't highlight.

Comment: OMG! I have just spent hours and hours trying to achieve this! I was looking at creating custom selectors, or background colour to hide the selector effect... Thanks heaps!

Comment: It is really weird... setClickable(true) means not clickable.
hope this will not be fixed in the future...XDD

Comment: This comment is years later, but it might help beginners so here goes: the `onClick` event is handled by the child `View` itself, and the `OnItemClick` is handled by the parent `ListView`. so by enabling `OnClick` of the child `View`, you are overriding the `OnItemClick` of the `ListView`. Although this will work in practice, It's better not to do it this way, and Implement the methods of `ListAdapter` as shown by some answers below. hope that helps

Comment: This still works like this. I must say, unintuitive! And an amazing sentence construction.

Comment: unintuitive indeed, but works flawlessly with minimum efforts. Just added a comment on code to explain the event is captured beforehand with this simple trick to keep it clear.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not completely clear. I am interpreting your question as that you are expecting `onItemClick()` to not be called based upon your `setEnabled()` and `setClickable()` calls.

I'm not surprised that doesn't work, as `onItemClick()` is something `ListView` does, not the child view. Try overriding `areAllItemsEnabled()` and `isEnabled()` in your `ListAdapter` instead.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple reasons why your approach will not work.

1) `onItemClick` is only called due to keyboard events. Specifically `KeyKevent.KEYCODE_ENTER`. It is not called via any other code path. So, handling that even is only useful if you are attempting to provide keyboard/trackball support.

Android source code for AbsListView relevant methods:

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (isClickable() && isPressed() &&
                mSelectedPosition >= 0 && mAdapter != null &&
                mSelectedPosition < mAdapter.getCount()) {

            final View view = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition - mFirstPosition);
            if (view != null) {
                performItemClick(view, mSelectedPosition, mSelectedRowId);
                view.setPressed(false);
            }
            setPressed(false);
            return true;
        }
        break;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

public boolean performItemClick(View view, int position, long id) {
    if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
        playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(this, view, position, id);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

2) You are setting the clickable information directly on the view. The views displayed via any `AdapterView` are ethereal. They are created at the request of the `AdapterView` and only exist as long as the `AdapterView` needs them. You should not set any data on them that you want to keep. You can call `setEnabled` and `setClickable` on them for immediate effect but if you want that information to persist you need to store it somewhere the `Adapter` has access to so it can be recreated when the `AdapterView` recreates the `View` for that position.

3) You need to handle the `onClick` event for the actual `View` being clicked. Where you handle this is up to you. The best place is probably your `Adapter` which then may or may not pass it up to your `Activity` depending on what your design requirements are. That is where you need to handle your touch events.

See this code for a simple Activity:

```
public class PhoneTesting extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "PhoneTesting";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++) {
            strings.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }

        ListView list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, 0, 0, strings));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: " + id);
            }
        });

    }

    class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnClickListener {
        SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
        }

        SimpleAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        SimpleAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        SimpleAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView b = position % 2 == 0 ? new Button(this.getContext()) : new TextView(this.getContext());
            b.setText(this.getItem(position));

            b.setOnClickListener(this);

            return b;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView t = (TextView) v;
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + t.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return position % 2 == 0 ? false : true;
        }

    }
}
```

If you execute this code and click on any of the `View`s in the `ListView` you will notice in the logcat output that only `onClick` is being called. `onItemClick` is never called.

Also note that `isEnabled` in the adapter does not seem to effect if the `View` is clickable or not. I am not sure how to interpret that. What that means though is that if you want to control that property of the `View` the `Adapter` needs set that when the `View` is created and to somehow maintain that information.

Comment: I'd also need to override `areAllItemsEnabled()` in the Adapter, but thanks

Comment: Yea, forgot about that one. still onItemClick is only called via keyboard events.