# Disabled item in spinner list

Tags: android, spinner

I have a question for You !

I have 50 items in my spinner, can I disabled for example sixth item in my list ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the item from the array in your ListAdapter based on its position and call `setEnabled(false)` in the public `getView()` method.

Like this:

```
if (position==10) {
    convertView.setEnabled(false);
}
else{
    convertView.setEnabled(true);
}
```

You will probably need to override some other methods. Check those posts: 
 [Android ListView child View setEnabled() and setClickable() do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636270/android-listview-child-view-setenabled-and-setclickable-do-nothing) 
 [Android: How to disable list items on list creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183610/android-how-to-disable-list-items-on-list-creation)