# How to disable an autocomplete item?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want all the 'not available' item to be disabled i.e. the dropdown should stay intact when I click them.

[image]

I tried setting the `convertView` `clickable` `false`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Can't you add a condition in your "OnItemClickListener" ?

Comment: i did, but i m not able to avoid dropdown dismiss

Comment: I assume you have defined an Adapter for the dropdown. Inside the Adapter, customize your behavior in the getView & getDropdownView.

Comment: Yes i have a custom adapter, that why i have different views for unavailable items, but the onClick behavior is common for all the items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in your adapter's `getView()' method check

```java
if (text.equals("not available")) {
    convertView.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    convertView.setEnabled(true);
}
```

override in your adapter

```java
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // return false if position == position you want to disable
}
```

check it here  [Android ListView child View setEnabled() and setClickable() do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636270/android-listview-child-view-setenabled-and-setclickable-do-nothing)

Comment: setEnabled() does not enable or disable list items when called on the list item's view.

Comment: I've tries the first block of code, then second block of code, but it didn't appear to me that they should work if put together. Thanks!